# Artificially increasing the size of a dataset through duplication?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, conv-neural-network, data-science

I'm working on a machine learning project where I'm using a neural network to solve a binary classification problem, however, my dataset(in .csv format) is relatively small. It only has around 60 yes/no cases and although it was able to train, the accuracy wasn't very good. My solution to that was just duplicating the dataset and on each duplication, making tiny changes to the numbers, i.e., adding +-1 or multiplying by 0.999 to each number. By doing this I grew the size of the dataset to around 1100 new cases and it achieved much higher levels of accuracy. I was wondering if this is an actual technique used by ML researchers and if it is, does it have an actual official/academic name?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the process you are referring to is called data augmentation.

However, I would highly recommend you to not use neural networks on datasets with merely hundred to thousand rows. Ideally Neural networks are used to train models over large datasets.

Comment: It was for many years common practice to use Neural Networks with a few hundred rows. Actually Logisitic Regression which is a Neural Network can be trained with a hundred examples